# Bijections between disjoint sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Problem:Let $X,X'$ be disjoint sets and $Y,Y'$ be likewise disjoint. If $X\sim$ $Y$ and $X'\sim Y'$ then $X\cup X' \sim Y\cup Y'$ (for every sets $Z$ and $Z'$,the notation $Z \sim Z'$ means that there is a bijection from $Z$ to $Z'$).

My proof:

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ and $g: X'\rightarrow Y'$ be the respective bijections. Define $h: X\cup X' \rightarrow Y\cup Y'$ by $h(x)=$ 
$ \begin{cases} 
      f(x) & x\in X \\
      g(x) & x\in X' \\  
   \end{cases}$

. h is well defined:

Let $a=b$. Then either they are both in $X$ or both in $X'$, in either case, $f,g$ are well defined hence $h(a)=h(b)$.

Injective:
  Suppose $a\neq b$.
  Case (1): wlog suppose $a\in X$ and $b\in X'$. Then $f(a)\in Y$ and $g(b) \in Y'$, as $Y\cap Y' = \varnothing$ it follows that $f(a)\neq g(b)$ .

Case (2): wlog suppose $a,b \in X$ such that $a\neq b$. As $f$ is bijective, $f(a)\neq f(b)$ $\implies$ $h(a)\neq h(b)$.

Surjective:
  If $y\in Y\cup Y'$ then it is either in $Y$ or $Y'$, not both. As $f,g$ are surjective we can find an $x\in X'$ such that $f(x) = y$ . Similarly for $Y'$.

Can I have feedback, please?

Comment: Yea looks good to me

Comment: Not quite. The proof that $h$ is well defined does not make sense, for instance. It is not even clear from what is written what "being well defined" means.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo $x=y$ $\implies$ $h(x)=h(y)$

Comment: One cool thing: since $f$ and $g$ are sets of ordered pairs, you can just let $h$ be their union. To see it is a function: for any x in the domain of h, there will be only one $y \in Y \cup Y'$ such that $(x,y) \in h$. The ideia is the same as yours but maybe the argument gets more clear.

Comment: @topological Yes, that is trivial. If that is what you feel being well defined means, then unfortunately it looks as if you have not understood that concept.

Comment: @darkwatch that's a very nice way of looking at it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is essentially correct. Just pay attention to the following things:

1. In the proof of injectivity, there is a case (3): $a, b \in X'$ with $a \neq b$. Of course, this case is analogous to case (2), just replace $f$ with $g$ and use the injectivity of $g$ (maybe you omitted this case because it is similar to case (2), but it is better to mention it).
2. In the proof of surjectivity, after you say that either $y \in Y$ or $y \in Y'$, not both, you should conclude that: in the first, case there is $x \in X$ (and not in $X'$, as you wrote instead, I guess it is a typo) such that $f(x) = y$, since $f$ is surjective; in the second case, there is $x \in X'$ such that $g(x) = y$, since $g$ is surjective. Therefore, in both cases there is $x \in X \cup X'$ such that $h(x) = y$.
3. To be rigorous, your proof that $h$ is well defined is meaningless. Indeed, in this proof you use a functional notation for $h$ that makes sense only in the case you already know that $h$ is well defined. The rigorous approach would be to use first a relational notation for $h$, i.e. $h$ is defined as the binary relation from $X \cup X'$ to $Y \cup Y'$ such that 
   \begin{align}
   (x,y) \in h \text{ iff } 
   \begin{cases} x \in X \text{ and } y = f(x), \text{ or } \\
   x \in X' \text{ and } y = g(x)
   \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   Now, proving that $h$ is a well defined function amounts to prove that: 
   \begin{equation}\tag{*}
   \text{for every } x \in X \cup X' \text{ there is exactly one } y \in Y \cup Y' \text{ such that } (x,y) \in h.
   \end{equation} 
   Only after proving that the functional notation $y = h(x)$ for $(x,y) \in h$ makes sense. Are you able to prove (*)?

Comment: I thought a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is well defined if whenever $x=y$ in the domain we have $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @topologicalmagician - If $x = y$ then by necessity $f(x) = f(y)$, since $x$ and $y$ are the same object and so they are when $f$ is applied to them.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocoo what about multivalued functions? They aren't well defined. Or you could also think about it in terms of groups, like when you attempt to define multiplication on subgroups that are not normal.

Comment: @topologicalmagician - Please, be more specific: what is your question about multivalued functions? Note that a multivalued function is not a function because it does not satisfy the condition (*) in my answer. A multivalued function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ is a binary relation from $X$ to $Y$ that satisfy the following condition: for every $x \in X$ there exists some (possibly many) $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$. Please, note that the funcitonal notation $y = f(y)$ for a multivalued function $f$ is really misleading.

Comment: I see your point. Thank you very much.